# SQLalchemy Database error when using columns with lowercase names starting with underscore with Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

The problem is that if the name of a table or a column begins with an underscore and is written in lower case, then alchemy gives an invalid identifier database error in the case of Oracle. Previously, I wrote all table names in uppercase, there were no problems, but now Postgre support has been added and it has problems with uppercase.

E.g.,

```
class Blah(blahblah_base): 
_tablename_ = "_blahblah_"

_id_ = Column(INTEGER(), primary_key=True)
name = Column(String).
```

Please help me with a better solution.

Comment: for example 
class Blah(blahblah_base):

   \ __tablename\__ = "\_blahblah\_"

   \_id\_ = Column(INTEGER(), primary_key=True)
   name = Column(String)

Comment: Relevant: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/oracle.html#identifier-casing

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand how to get out of the situation with underscores at the beginning of names, names without underscores work fine in lower case

Comment: If you used to have Oracle working, it sounds like Postgres is the problem :)

Comment: I used Oracle, but I used upper case, which is not quite correct according to the documentation for alchemy. But it worked, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there is a problem with creating sql entity names which start with underscore, so to create such entity you need to use double quotes which in turn make it case sensetive.

So in my case needed a workaround to solve the problem.
This is example how I did it:

```
class Files(base):
    __tablename__ = get_name("_files_")

    __id__ = Column(get_name("__id__"), INTEGER(), primary_key=True)
    file_name = Column(get_name("file_name"), String(256), nullable=False)
    file_type = Column(get_name("file_type"), String(32))
```

where "get_name" is the function that returns uppercase name if db type is oracle and lowercase for all other databases

most likely this is not the best solution, but it helped me